# puzzled by format of PHP multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Sorry if this is a duplication of anyone elses question but in my eyes it doesn't appear to match any other PHP multi dimensional array questions on here. And I've read them all. :-(

I'm trying to access values of this array (which I have no control over).  But it's format is puzzling me and as yet I can't get at the values how I thought I should be able to.

This my JSON array example.

```
 {"Result":[{"Links":[{"UrlTo":"blahblahA/","Visited":1380104406,"FirstSeen":1375979058,"PrevVisited":1379817016,"Anchor":"text links","Type":"Text","Flag":[],"TextPre":"","TextPost":""}],"Index":0,"Rating":18.44400799929153,"UrlFrom":"blahblahB","IpFrom":"209.18.x.11","Title":"home page","LinksInternal":16,"LinksExternal":5,"Size":13107},{"Links":[{"UrlTo":"blahblahABC","Visited":1380574695,"FirstSeen":1375979100,"PrevVisited":1379224472,"Anchor":"text links","Type":"Text","Flag":[],"TextPre":"","TextPost":""}],"Index":1,"Rating":11.02675617091105,"UrlFrom":"blahblahXYZ","IpFrom":"209.18.x.11","Title":"Random title","LinksInternal":16,"LinksExternal":5,"Size":13107}]}
```

I naively thought that assigning this Json array to $arr
Then decoding like so.

```
$arr = json_decode($str,true);
```

once done i could reference the array values like so...

```
$UrlTo = $arr['Result']['Links']['UrlTo'];
```

But I'm clearly not understanding this right.
I've spent a lot of time googling, reading and still don't get it.
I think it will be obvious to someone more experienced than I?
Can someone help me understand the naivity of my approach.

Comment: Just put a `print_r($arr)` in your file to see the way the array is build

Comment: Does this work: `$UrlTo = $arr['Result'][0]['Links'][0]['UrlTo'];`?

Comment: `[]` stands for an array. `[{}]` is an object inside an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's:

```
$arr['Result'][0]['Links'][0]['UrlTo'];
```

`$arr['Result']` is an array, as is `$arr['Result'][0]['Links']`

To get the other result, do:

```
$arr['Result'][1]['Links'][0]['UrlTo'];
```

Comment: thanks for all comments and this answer from Frits was great.  I was sure it was one of the variations I'd already tried but clearly not.

after a bit of fiddling I worded out that some of the variables are accessed slightly differently.  Would not have got there without this concept being explained to me though.  Thank you. :-)